# $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-experience, lightning-connect

i am calling this method from the save button in lightning component.

```
getaVal : function(component, event, helper) {
    var updateValues = [];
    var lstInsert = [];
    var lstUpdate = [];
    var arrrr;
    var mapSize = component.get("v.fullMap");

    for (var singlekey in mapSize) {
        for(var i=0; i<mapSize[singlekey].length; i++) {
            updateValues.push(mapSize[singlekey][i]);
        }
    }

    console.log('updateValues:::',updateValues);
    arrrr = updateValues;

    for(var i=0; i<arrrr.length; i++) {
        if(arrrr[i].hasOwnProperty('Id')) {
            lstUpdate.push(arrrr[i]);   
        }
        else if(arrrr[i].hasOwnProperty('Name')) {
            delete arrrr[i].Name;
            lstInsert.push(arrrr[i]);
        }
    }

    if(lstUpdate.length !=0)
        helper.updateCounterBid(component, event, helper, lstUpdate);
    if(lstInsert.length !=0)    
        helper.insertCounterParty(component, event, helper, lstInsert);

        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

}
```

Comment: Where are you viewing this lightning component?

Comment: at custom tabs in record page

Comment: Define "not working." That's a vague term. Do you see any errors on the console? How about the Developer Console logs? Any popups or messages on the screen? Can you make a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy-paste to fiddle around with that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3):

'e.force:refreshView' is available only inside the lightning container and wont be available when you use lightning out on VF .
They don't work in VF / classic view or in standalone apps

Answer (score 0):

You could try refreshing the component once your insert / update array size is not empty, like:

```
if( lstUpdate.length > 0 || lstInsert.length > 0  ) { $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); }
```

(or) can you can add it inside your helper functions success result `helper.updateCounterBid(component, event, helper, lstUpdate);` (or) in 
`helper.insertCounterParty(component, event, helper, lstInsert);`

```
action.setCallback(cmp,
    function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
            ***$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();***
        } else {
             //do something
        }
    }
);
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue too. Even using navigation service did not work for me. I just redirect it to the record view as below:

```
window.location = '/lightning/r/'+ objectApiName +'/'+ recordId + '/view';
```

In case anyone wants to try navigation:

```
<!--Add navigation service to your component-->
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

Use the below code in a callback or action to navigate to the record:

```
    let navService = cmp.find("navService");
    let pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            "recordId": recordId,
            "objectApiName": sObjectName,
            "actionName": "view"
        }
    };
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

Answer (score -2):

You must put this call into a callback function like shown here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm

Comment: hey on callback also not working

Comment: Have u try to put the call after the insert/update statement inside the helper? How does this functions look like?

Comment: man not working

Comment: page is not refreshing